# Create playable file from raw rtp packets

Tags: rtp

I have a pcap file that contains rtp data received and sent over the network. In wireshark I use follow udp stream to access raw data for source and destination. Then I save source and destinations files separately. How can I extract audio/video data from these files and convert them to a playable file?

Answer (score 0):

These links provide the info you need:

[Cisco community - use audacity](https://community.cisco.com/t5/ip-telephony-and-phones/how-to-save-rtp-streams-from-wireshark-and-play-it-using-an/td-p/1966791)

[Wireshark wiki - rtpdump](https://wiki.wireshark.org/rtpdump)